# BMXAA8342E There was an error loading the OSLC interaction cache

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, oslc

I have created a new object structure and OSLC Resource in Maximo with an intent of using it in Maximo Anywhere. 
After making the change I have reverted the changes using the Maximo UI and
restarted the Maximo application. 
Now I am unable to query any of the OSLC objects.
I am using Maximo 7.6, Anywhere 7.5.2.
Full description of the error whenever I try to access any of the OSLC object is 
"**BMXAA8342E There was an error loading the OSLC interaction cache. There might be corrupted database entries for the OSLC interaction. If interaction data was loaded outside of the OSLC Providers application, verify that the data was loaded correctly.**"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message it refers to the OSLC Providers application, this is the bit that gives all the spi_wm, etc. namespaces.  If you have reverted Maximo correctly the error should not be in Maximo.

It might be an old namesapce reference in your application.
My starting point for these kinds of things is to 
1) go to your object structure in Maximo, then Select Action -> Generate Schema View XML
2) in your Eclipse project run the rdfs puller ant task

Then rebuild and run your app.

If that does not work in your Eclipse project (after taking a backup) try deleting everything in oslc-docs/resources/rdf/oslc/shapes, then re-running the rdfs puller.

Then rebuild and run your app.

Comment: Above steps did not resolve the issue. I had to revert the OSLC resource changes through Maximo OSLC Resources application.